# Script to list Power Query source dependencies in multiple Excel files

Tags: python, excel, vba, powerquery

I use Power Query (PQ) for quite complex data flow. Many queries in single file gradually lengthen  computing times, so I split PQ to multiple Excel files.

I want to know, what files are dependent on the others. I have found something like [this](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T007799_Discovering_Dependent_Workbooks.html) for cell references.

**Question**: how can I get list of referenced sources (filenames for Excel files) in PQ over multiple files in specified directory?

I have thought of solutions:

- VBA - I am able to update cited script to traverse files, but I don't know proper methods to access Power Query sources.
- python - my brute force approach would be to temporarily unzip `XLS?` file and parse XML for used sources.

Is there any framework or working sample, that would list all PQ sources from specific `XLS?` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access powerQuery sources like this:

```
Set t = ThisWorkbook.Queries("Table1")
tf = t.Formula
```

Comment: Just for the record: I have used exact property combined with python and win32com library. Strugled with Excel 2010 version (no Queries() method), everything works with Excel 2016.